# Clustering Markers in Apple Maps for Flutter

Tags: flutter, markerclusterer, apple-maps

I’ve searched online all over the place, but I can’t find any way to implement clustering for my `Markers` (Annotations in iOS terminology) within the existing plugins that display `Apple Maps` in `flutter`.

Does anyone have any advice for me on how I would go about doing this?  I would prefer not to have to write my own custom plugin if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The `apple_maps_flutter` GitHub has an [annotations example](https://github.com/LuisThein/apple_maps_flutter/blob/master/example/lib/annotation_icons.dart).

Just change `_createAnnotation()` to

```
  Set<Annotation> _createAnnotation() {
    return <Annotation>[
      Annotation(
        annotationId: AnnotationId("annotation_1"),
        position: LatLng(10.000000, 10.000000),
        icon: _annotationIcon,
      ),
      Annotation(
        annotationId: AnnotationId("annotation_2"),
        position: LatLng(20.000000, 20.000000),
        icon: _annotationIcon,
      ),
      Annotation(
        annotationId: AnnotationId("annotation_3"),
        position: LatLng(30.000000, 30.000000),
        icon: _annotationIcon,
      ),
    ].toSet();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use apple maps on iOS and google maps on Android.

I found a plugin for clustering which is only for **google_maps_flutter**.
https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_cluster_manager

What I did it was to extend that manager and add to it same logic what **google_maps_cluster_manager** does but with types created for **apple_maps_flutter** plugin.

Maybe you could do it same way.

Answer (score 0):

@ https://stackoverflow.com/users/6657226/piotr-wysocki
n my case I had to use apple maps on iOS and google maps on Android.

I found a plugin for clustering which is only for google_maps_flutter. https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_cluster_manager

What I did it was to extend that manager and add to it same logic what google_maps_cluster_manager does but with types created for apple_maps_flutter plugin.

Please provie code for this apple map clusters